# Ultramem VM Instances Access

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to determine how I can obtain access to Google's new ultramem instances, as described here:

https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/05/Introducing-ultramem-Google-Compute-Engine-machine-types.html

I can't see them from within 'create an instance' in my GCP, and I checked to make sure the region is matching what the blog post advertises as an available region.

Perhaps somebody has some information on this, or can tell me how I can contact Google and ask about this without having to purchase a support package.

Comment: When selecting machine type, I was able to view the ultramem but i had to scroll completely down. Bronze package is free. Menu > Support

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure it out now. The issue was that I was trying to configure the machine using 'Customise' as opposed to using the 'Basic' view. I can see the ultra-mem in the basic view now.

Answer (score 0):

GCP offers different **machine type** alternatives that can be used when creating VMs in GCE, such as predifined and custom machines.

- [Predefined machine types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#predefined_machine_types) - Have a fixed collection of resources that come in four different classes. Standard, High-memory, High-CPU and Memory-optimized (ultramem machines). These machine types options can be selected by using the Machine type dropdown displayed at the **New VM instance** section when [Creating an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#startinginstancewithimage).

[image: Predefined machine types]

- [Customize machine types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#custom_machine_types) - Used to specify the number of vCPUs and the amount of system memory for your instance. This option can be selected by using the **Customize** link displayed at the **New VM instance** section when [Creating an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#startinginstancewithimage).

[image: Select customize machine type]